# Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side

Tags: matlab

When I gave four lambda values then it gives me an error that it's Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side. But for a single value like 36, 38, 40, or 42 it's ok.

```
R = [0.5:0.1:2.25];
    Vs1= [120];
    Vs2 = R.*Vs1;
    H1=[5:5:25];
    rho = [2000 2000];
    lambda = [36 38 40 42];

    for j=1:length(Vs2),
        Vs = [Vs1 Vs2(j)];
        for i=1:length(H1)
            H2=30-H1(i);
            d=[H1(i),H2];
            Vs30(j,i)=Vs30_fun(d,Vs);
            
        end
    end
    
    
    for j=1:length(Vs2),
        Vs = [Vs1 Vs2(j)];Vp=2.*Vs;
        for i=1:length(H1)
            d=[H1(i) Inf];
            VR(j,i)=lv_fun(d,Vs,Vp,rho,lambda);
            
        end
    end
    
    M=VR<Vs30;
    [m,n]=size(M);
    VR=zeros(length(Vs2),length(H1));
    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n        
            if M(i,j)==0
                plot(H1(i),R(j), 'r*')
                hold on
    %                drawnow();
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 VR(j,i)=lv_fun(d,Vs,Vp,rho,lambda);
```

You didn't initialize VR. I suggest you initialize the variable before and plugin values later.
try this before the loop.

```
VR=zeros(length(Vs2),length(H1));
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, but I want to give all the lambda values at the same time now, I means (36, 38, 40, 42) I want to give these value at the same time

Comment: I suggest you research about the `.` operator a little bit.